# In bootstrap.css, why is *display added after display?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on improving my basic css fundamentals and came across this question that I could not seem to google the answer.

In twitter bootstrap 2.3.2, there are a couple times within bootstrap.css where the stylesheet is as the following:

```
ul.inline > li,
ol.inline > li {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

and another example would be:

```
.row-fluid .span12 {
  width: 91.48936170212765%;
  *width: 91.43617021276594%;
 }
```

* is a universal selector. If they added *width after "width", *width will override the "width" before, correct? Please advise.

PS: I already researched this question and was not able to find the answer. If this is similar, I would really appreciate a link to the other post, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an explorer hack. Version 8 read this while others ignore it.

IE in sometimes need different css then other versions.

This is a refernce from a google search:

*explorer 8 asterisk hack*

[javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml) and there are many more.

Note it's in the unrecomended section. 
http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Comment: please expand on your answer. Provide links and references if necessary.